# Microsoft Bot Framework - Python

Tags: botframework

Im trying to develop a Chatbot using Microsoft Bot Framework in Python.

I'm trying to utilize the Conversation Update Activity so that whenever a user joins the Conversation , the Bot responds to the user using a simple "Hello"

I have utilized Conversation Update but now the Bot throws in 2 responses which i believe is one for the user and one for itself since there are 2 people in a conversation.

Below is the Code. Can you please help me?

```
from botbuilder.core import TurnContext,ActivityHandler
from botbuilder.schema import ActivityTypes,ChannelAccount

class ActivityBot(ActivityHandler):
        async def on_message_activity(self,turn_context:TurnContext):
            await turn_context.send_activity(turn_context.activity.text)
        async def on_members_added_activity(self,member_added : ChannelAccount,turn_context:TurnContext):
            await turn_context.send_activity("Hello Welcome to Echo Bot!!!")
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: there is a great sample for this purpose: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-send-welcome-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python

Comment: What channel are you using? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @Kyle Delaney I'm using Bot Emulator test the ChatBot

Comment: @SwapnilKadam - Did you read the tutorial Hessel linked?

Comment: @KyleDelaney: Yes I did...But wasnot able to follow along much..Im a beginner when it comes to Bot Framework...I did try to figure it out but wasnt able too..Do you want to have a look at the entire code?

Comment: @SwapnilKadam - I don't think seeing all your code will be necessary. We can already see that you didn't put any logic in your `on_members_added_activity` handler to check which member was added. The document already explains how to do that, so what are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @SwapnilKadam - Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney NO